# Passing soundpool to multiple activities in Android

Tags: android

Basically, in a short explanation, I am making a sound board. Once I run the initial activity, it adds all sound clips to the soundpool. I then have two other activities that are to organize the sound clips, and I would like to use the previously loaded soundpool so that there isn't move load time when switching between activities. I am fairly new to this Android coding, so please make things in simple terms!

EDIT: Also, does anybody know how to stop the playback on a second button click? Not as in clicking a different button, I understand that, but if the same button is clicked, it will stop it?

My main activity:

`private SoundManager mSoundManager;`

```
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);      
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mSoundManager = new SoundManager();
    mSoundManager.initSounds(getBaseContext());
    mSoundManager.addSound(0, R.raw.stop_playing);
    mSoundManager.addSound(1, R.raw.sound1);
    mSoundManager.addSound(2, R.raw.sound2);
    mSoundManager.addSound(3, R.raw.sound3);
```

Dealing with soundpool stuff:

`public void initSounds(Context theContext) { 
         mContext = theContext;
         mSoundPool = new SoundPool(1, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0); 
         mSoundPoolMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>(); 
         mAudioManager = (AudioManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

    }`

```
public void addSound(int Index,int SoundID)
{
    mSoundPoolMap.put(Index, mSoundPool.load(mContext, SoundID, 1));

}

public void pauseSound(){
    mSoundPool.autoPause();
}

public void stopSound(){
    mSoundPool.stop(playingNumber);
}


public int playSound(int index) { 

     int streamVolume = mAudioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC); 
     int soundId = mSoundPool.play(mSoundPoolMap.get(index), streamVolume, streamVolume, 1, 0, 1f);
     mSoundPool.play(mSoundPoolMap.get(index), streamVolume, streamVolume, 1, 0, 1f); 
     playingNumber = index;
     return playingNumber;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alwade create Application class, and create static SoundManager instance in the your application class, and add needed sounds to SoundManager in the Initial activity. Then you can use current Soundmanager in other activities. Change SoundManager class to static class.

**For example:**

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    public static SoundManager soundManager;

    public static SoundManager getSoundManager() {
        return soundManager;
    }

    public static void setSoundManager(SoundManager soundManagerIns) {
        soundManager = soundManagerIns;
    }

}
```

**and in the initial activity create instance and set it to :**

```
mSoundManager = new SoundManager();
mSoundManager.initSounds(getApplicationContext);
mSoundManager.addSound(0, R.raw.stop_playing);
mSoundManager.addSound(1, R.raw.choo_choo);
mSoundManager.addSound(2, R.raw.all);
mSoundManager.addSound(3, R.raw.hearts);

MyApplication.setSoundManager(mSoundManager);
```

**Then you can get this SoundManager in the other activities:**

SoundManager sManager = MyApplication.getSoundManager();

This is my example project: [SoundPoolExample](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BxNIUTd_m1x8MGlyY2VlNTZERDg/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: But if were using void for getSoundManager(), how can we return something? I haven't used java in a long time, so I apologize

Comment: Sorry alwade24, I wrote this code in the text of Editor because I scored prostitution look at my post editet.

Comment: Sorry for that late answer your commentary, I'm logged in to stackoverflow now.

Comment: ahhh okay. And not a problem, I may not get around to this until later, I've got a COBOL final in the morning, so I have some studying to do. I'll mark it as answered, but I may have more questions! I appreciate the help!!

Comment: What do you mean when you say "create instance and set it to"?

Comment: You need to create at least one instance of the class SoundManager for using.

Comment: And set this intance to soundManager field of MyApplication class (MyApplication.setSoundManager(mSoundManager))

Comment: I then get the message "The method newInstance(void) is undefined for the type SoundManager".... Do I want to create that as a method in SoundManager? I apologize, like I said, I haven't had java in a few years, and I don't think we ever dealt with creating instances.... So I'm kinda in the dark, I may not have even done that right

Comment: alwade24 you create SoundManager soundManager = new SoundManager(); and set its to app class: MyApplication.setSoundManager(soundManager);. Send your code to my email.

Comment: See example, i set access to your email, you can download this project: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BxNIUTd_m1x8MGlyY2VlNTZERDg/edit?usp=sharing